# Issues connecting to HP ProCurve switches

Tags: switch, hp

We are having a very strange issue trying to connect to our infrastructure switches via SSH. When you first try connecting to them, the switches will prompt for the password - and then just sit there after it is entered.

If you create a second SSH session to the switch (while letting the first one remain open and just sitting there) it will let you log right in.

The switches are doing the same thing with RADIUS and local authentication.

The other strange part to all of this, is that about 10 switches started doing it all at the same time. As far as actual configuration of the switches, nothing has changed.

Occasionally, one switch will start working like normal, but then stop again.

These are all HP ProCurve managed switches, but all different models/firmware.

Some switches that are not working are using the same firmware as others that are working.

**UPDATE: 20130312**

I am also seeing this same behavior when trying to use telnet. The first telnet session just hangs there, and the second telnet session will let me log in.

Rebooting the switches seems to get them working, but I still have 5 production switches that cannot easily be rebooted because of their production roles.

Is anyone aware of anything else that can be switched on/off that may reset the logon for remote management or something like that?

Comment: Which model switches are you using? And does using the serial port work any better?

Comment: It is very strange as it is a bunch of different models (2610, 2810, 2910). The issue is with console, telnet, and SSH. So far only a reboot seems to fix it - have a couple remaining but no luck figuring it out yet.

Comment: This has happened to me for quite a long time now and I always need to reboot to overcome - it seems to happen especially after firmware updates and on varying models and versions of procurve. The workaround of logging in twice is enough for me and I then reboot to clear the issue. It would be interesting to know what is causing this though!

Comment: I have had the exact same problem using SSH, i.e. the session 'hangs' after entering the password.
However on some occasions I can connect from a different source subnet (provided its permitted in 'ip authorized-managers). On other occasions, I connected via SSH twice, both sessions hung after entering the password, but a third attempt (all from the same source) succeeded (leaving the first two 'hung' sessions open as the OP says).